# Credit Card Number Masking with ion-input - Ionic3

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, ionic3

I tried 3-4 npm modules to mask my ion-input for Credit Card numbers to be Groups of 4.

But every module has their own errors in modules.

I want to mask my ion-input to be groups of 4 (Credit Card number.)

**Notes**: There should be some description problem, please ignore it.

Answer (score 5):

I solved by manual logic to mask input:

In `ion-input` i bound `blur` event and invoked `mask()` on blur.

Here is the code of mask Function:

```
mask(event) {

setTimeout(() => {
  var inputTxt = event.srcElement.value;
  inputTxt = inputTxt ? inputTxt.split(" ").join("") : "";
  inputTxt = inputTxt.length > 16 ? inputTxt.substring(0, 16) : inputTxt;
  this.cardNumber = this.maskString(inputTxt);
 }, 500);
}

 maskString(inputTxt) {
   inputTxt = inputTxt.replace(/\D/g, "");
   inputTxt = inputTxt.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/, "$1 $2");
   inputTxt = inputTxt.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/, "$1 $2");
   inputTxt = inputTxt.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/, "$1 $2");
   inputTxt = inputTxt.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/, "$1 $2");
   return inputTxt;
 }
```

Thanks [Referenceed Link](https://www.codementor.io/syseverton/how-and-why-i-built-ionic-3-cpf-cnpj-input-mask-drendh04g)